# Calculate percentiles using SQL for a group/partition

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

I want to calculate the percentiles for a given partition/group in SQL. For example the input data looks like -

```
CustID     Product ID     quantity_purchased    
1          111                2
2          111                3
3          111                2 
4          111                5
1          222                2
2          222                6
4          222                7
6          222                2
```

I want to get percentiles on each product ID group. The output should be -

```
Product ID    min      25%      50%      75%     max
    111        2        2       2.5      3.5      5
    222        2        2        4       6.25     7
```

How to achieve this using SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`percentile_cont()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/percentile_cont.html):

```
select product_id, min(quantity_purchased), max(quantity_purchased),
       percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by quantity_purchased),
       percentile_cont(0.50) within group (order by quantity_purchased),
       percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by quantity_purchased)
from t
group by product_id;
```